# How can I get the name of column that have NaN values in the pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| Hour | Temp | Hum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01:00 | 30.3 | 70 |
| 02:00 | 29.2 | 72 |
| 03:00 | 29.8 | **NaN** |
| 04:00 | 28.9 | 80 |

I wanna print what the name of the columns that have NaN values.

Example:

```
The column **Hum** has empty values
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.isna()` + `.any()`:

```py
for c in df.columns:
    if df[c].isna().any():
        print(f"The column {c} has empty values")
```

Prints:

```
The column Hum has empty values
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a whole list of your columns with null values by running:

```
df.isnull().any().loc[lambda b: b == True]
```